# Ad not displaying on my page, what do I do?

Tags: html, ads, adsense, admob, adsense-api

Here's the code

```
<ins class="adsbygoogle"
     style="display:block; text-align:center;"
     data-ad-layout="in-article"
     data-ad-format="fluid"
     data-ad-client="ca-pub-9121789382833091"
     data-ad-slot="5430801878"></ins>
<script>
     (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script></div>
```

I put it in body and have adblocker disabled (yes, I waited for 2 hours). Are there any limits to website visitors amount or I did wrong code?

Comment: We need to see the css

Comment: @FirstName I haven’t any

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the script tag loading the library:

```
<script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>

<ins class="adsbygoogle"
     style="display:block; text-align:center;"
     data-ad-layout="in-article"
     data-ad-format="fluid"
     data-ad-client="ca-pub-9121789382833091"
     data-ad-slot="5430801878"></ins>
<script>
     (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script></div>
```

Comment: Thx, but it’s there in <head> and I tried it both in head and body, nothing works. I heard I need to wait up to one month.

Comment: What does https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/pagead/ads... call return?

Comment: I checked my code and I really forgot to put library there so I fixed it and it doesn't show any errors but the ad is still not displaying. I'm going to wait for 2 hours and ask if it doesn't work

Comment: Ok, that's what I get: "Failed to load resource: the server googleads.g.doubleclick.net/pagead/LOTSOFTEXTHERE responded with a status of 403 ()"